# Converting some elements of a python list and preserving the rest

Tags: python, list, converters

I am looking for an elegant way to convert some elements of a list and preserve the rest.

Consider the following list:

```
list_ = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I would like to convert `list_` to `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]`, of course I can write a for loop with some if-statements like:

```
list_ = [1 if i == 1 or i == 5 else list_[i] for i in range(len(list_))]
```

However, I am looking a basic way, which copies the elements where the values are equal to `_`, and convertes the rest to the given value (in this case 1) like:

```
list_ = [_, 1, _, _, _, 1] in list_
```

Is there a pythonic way to do that? or should I write a function for it?

Additionally, sometimes the converted elements are not equal to 0, but for example 'x'.

E.g.:

```
list_ = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
# some magic functions etc... for converting 1st element to 'x' and 5th to 2
magic([_, 'x', _, _, _, 2], list_)

in>>> list_
out>> [0, 'x', 1, 1, 0, 2]
```

Comment: I have no idea what is your reasoning behind the expected output. You sample code produces `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, not `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]`.

Comment: it was an example, I was not trying to produce the expected result. However, if I would write the if-statement then it would be correct output!

Comment: So kind of like `np.where(list_ == list2_, list_, list2_)`?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal - I need to try this! it might be what I am looking for

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `for index in [1, 5]: list_[index] = 1`?

Comment: @zvone - nothing wrong with it, its just I need to convert lots of these lists, and the changed index of them actually means something in the other application. So  what I am changing and replacing matters, and I need to be able to see it fast. Eg, when I just look `[_, 1, _]`, I know the first element is changed and rest is the same (ofc, this does not work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_ = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

mask = [None, 1, None, None, None, 1]

l = [el_mask if el_mask is not None else el_list for el_list, el_mask in zip(list_, mask)]

print(l) # [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Your problem pretty much boils down to taking two lists, and combining them with one taking precedence over the other one.

You can combine 2 lists using the zip function, which will give you tuples of respective elements (`[(0, None), (0, 1), (1, None), (1, None), (0, None), (0, 1)]`). Then you just need to pick correct element between the 2 in the tuple.

If you really want `_` instead of `None` in the mask, you can assign it like any other variable. You'd need to make sure though that nothing in the same scope will use in any other context. For example, `_` is often used as a throwaway variable in the for loop, e.g. `for _ in range(10)` if you just want something repeated 10 times.

```
_ = None
mask = [_, 1, _, _, _, 1]
```

Comment: can we change None to _  for better readibility?

Comment: `_` is not something that is defined in Python. You could do `_ = None` assignment, making `_` a normal variable that behaves in the same way as None, but I'm not sure if that would really improve readability.

Comment: it does work though

Comment: @oakca I've expanded on the `_ = None` in the edit with required caveat.

Answer (score -1):

In Python you will rarely need to do for with `range(len(sequence))` - if you are doing so, that is, actually, an indicative you are being "unpythonic"

In this case, you almost got to the ideal way of doing the replace - but for this thing: the `for` *already* iterates your initial list elements: no need to have an `i` index, and then fetch the element at that position:

```
list_ = [1 if element == "value_to_replace" else element for element in list_]
```

Comment: That will just produce ones all over

Comment: In the question code, `i` is not the element of the list, but the index. As I understand the question, they want to convert all but a few elements in the list to `1`.

Comment: @KonstantinTarashchanskiy - additionally not just to one, to given value. So in this sense it could be also 'x' for example.

Comment: not exactly har dto fix, and not the point either.